# How to increase performance a chat app with Firebase with Xamarin.forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a chat application with Firebase and after creating it I am facing the issue that it is too slow. When a message is sent it will go to the server first and then it will show in the message list.

Can I save chat locally or can I show message on my thread before saving on db?

Here is my chat page:

```
namespace XamarinChatApp.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ChatPage : ContentPage
    {
        DBFire db = new DBFire();
        Room rm = new Room();
        public ChatPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RoomPage, Room>(this, "RoomProp", (page, data) =>
            {
                rm = data;    
                _lstChat.BindingContext = db.subChat(data.Key);    
                MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<RoomPage, Room>(this, "RoomProp");    
            });    
        }
        async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // firsth chat object
            //room name 1---okey

            var chatOBJ = new Chat { UserMessage = _etMessage.Text, UserName = User.UserName };
            _etMessage.Text = "";
            await db.saveMessage(chatOBJ, rm.Key);
        }

        async void Upload_Photo(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // firsth chat object
            //room name 1---okey

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            var imgData = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions());

            await db.saveImage(imgData.GetStream());
            // _img1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(imgData.GetStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define 'too slow'? Firebase is very fast and responses should be milliseconds. If you are not seeing that, there's either an issue with the internet connection or something else causing the issue.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you describe the desired behaviour and state what you have tried and why it is not working.

Comment: when user sends a message. I dont want the user to wait until data gets updates. Cloud Functions takes 2-3 seconds for me. Message sender should show his message immediate when click to send. How I can do that?